# How do i make this url Page format?

Tags: web

Hello can anyone help me about this

How to make website url page with "/" sign in the end. For example my url page is https://website.com/page1 , But i want to make it to be https://website.com/page1/

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to server's filesystem, you could create a directory named "page1" and move the page into it; then rename the page to the default server's index name (ex. "index.html" or "index.php").

This way, when the user asks for "https://website.com/page1/", the server answers with the index of the directory (that you defined in  file).

Comment: This only works if you're using a software like Apache and you can edit/create files/directories on server's web root

Comment: thanks for your response. But after i try it, It's not work. its still the same "not found". I had already make the new directory named "page1" and move my page also rename it to index.html

Both "https:// website.com/page1" and "https:// website.com/page1/" is not found

Comment: Is web page an HTML file?

Comment: Also do you know what software is your server running? (es Apache, nginx, ..)

Comment: Yes, the web is html and its apache